# Integral Convergence with parameters

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I am finding it hard to approach this question:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} {1-\cos(x)^a\over x^b}\, dx$$

and I need to determine for which positive values of $a,b$ the integral converges.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the answer a,b $\in R-{a=0 ,b=1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahmed Hussein's deleted answer is basically correct: near $x=0$ we have $1-\cos(x)^a \sim \frac a2 x^2$, and so the integral converges or diverges along with $\int_0 \frac1{x^{b+2}}\,dx$, which is to say, converges when $b<3$ and diverges when $b\ge3$. The integral isn't improper at $x=\frac\pi2$, so nothing needs checking there. (The question specifies $a,b$ positive, but this argument works for any real $b$ and for $a$ negative as well; when $a=0$, clearly the integral converges (to say the least).)

Comment: could you please tell me how did you get to (a/2)*x^2

Comment: by calculating its Maclaurin series